# Getting multivalue from the list of structs from nested structs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this schema of my data frame, the keys inside hosts are variables, basically, these are the hostnames and don't have any pattern  Eg: ae0s01, aadasde002, sfvu75ae003

```
 |-- hosts: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae001: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00x: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae003: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae001x: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae001sd: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00cv: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae001sdee struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae005: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00105: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00107: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00108: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00109: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ae00110: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- accountID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cluster: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to fetch the comma-separated list of accountId and clusters.

I have written the UDF to get his value but the parsing is very slow in the UDF. Can this be done in more effective way, or there are some problems or memory leak in my code

Mycode

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from pyspark.sql import Row

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, lpad, max, upper
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from  pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct, col
import json
import datetime


@udf
def extract_account_ids(hosts_struct):
    account_ids = set()
    clusters = set()

    try:
        for all_key in hosts_struct.asDict().keys():
            nested_struct = hosts_struct.asDict()[all_key]
            if nested_struct:
                if "accountID" in nested_struct:
                    if nested_struct["accountID"]:
                        account_ids.add(nested_struct["accountID"])
                if "cluster" in nested_struct:
                    if nested_struct["cluster"]:
                        clusters.add(nested_struct["cluster"])
        return ",".join(account_ids) + ":" + ",".join(clusters)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return ""


df = spark.read.json(path_1)
df2 = df.select(col("hosts"))
df3 = df2.withColumn("accounts:clusters", extract_account_ids(col("hosts")))\
        .withColumn("date", lit("2023-09-09"))

df4 = df3.select(col("accounts:clusters"), col("date"))
df4.write.format('csv').mode("append").save("s3a://ankur/2023-09-09/")
```

output

```
"accountID-1, accountID-2, accountID-3: cluster-1,cluster-2","2023-09-09"
```

Comment: could you add the expected output?

Comment: added the sample output

Answer (score 0):

Structure `hosts` child column names can be taken, concatenated with colon, and passed to `concat_ws`. Scala code, guess, can be converted to Python:

```
val hostsColumn = df.schema.find(col => col.name == "hosts").get

// ae001, ae00x, ae003
val childStructNames = hostsColumn.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields.map(_.name)
val concatenatedByColonColumns = childStructNames.map(name => concat(col("hosts." + name + ".accountID"), lit(":"), col("hosts." + name + ".cluster")))

val result = df.select(concat_ws(",", concatenatedByColonColumns: _*).as("result"))
```

Comment: Throwing this Exception
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [FIELD_NOT_FOUND] N

As the host is not the same for all the fields

Comment: If "hosts" child fields are not only structures with 'accountID' and 'cluster', this fields can be filtered. Only child fields which are structures can be taken.

Answer (score 0):

First, flatten the first layer and extract `accountID` and `cluster`. Then, use `concat_ws` to concatenate all `accountID` and `cluster` separately. Finally, concatenate the csv-styled `accountID` and `cluster`.

```
df = df.select('hosts.*')

df = df.select(*[col(f'{x}.accountID').alias(f'{x}_accountID') for x in df.columns],
               *[col(f'{x}.cluster').alias(f'{x}_cluster') for x in df.columns])

df = (df.select(concat_ws(',', *[x for x in df.columns if x.endswith('accountID')]).alias('accountID'),
                concat_ws(',', *[x for x in df.columns if x.endswith('cluster')]).alias('cluster'))
      .select(concat(col('accountID'), lit(': '), col('cluster')).alias('host')))
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|host                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|accountID-1,accountID-2,accountID-3: cluster-1,cluster-2|
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```